# Tic Tac Toe Winner Checker Issue

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am relatively new to coding and Java and for my CS-173 class, I was tasked with creating a Tic Tac Toe game. However, when it came to creating the method for determining a winner, whenever I achieved a "win", the code never ran saying I won. I do have the code to check each way to win however, I pulled it from the code in order to do some personal troubleshooting. Also, my apologies for the bad code.

```
     public static void playGame(char[][] board, int size){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int turn = 0;
    int spaces = board.length * board.length;
    boolean valid = false;
    boolean winner = false;

    for (int i = 0; i<spaces; i++){
      int startchecker = 3;
      int xcord = 0;
      int ycord = 0;

      do{      
        do{

          System.out.println("Player 1 please type your coordinates with a space");
            xcord = input.nextInt();
            ycord = input.nextInt();


           valid = isValid (board, xcord, ycord);

         if(i >= spaces){

         }   


        }while(!valid);      
          board[xcord][ycord] = 'X';
        printBoard(board);
         winner = isWinner(board);

        do{
            System.out.println("Player 2 please type your coordinates with a space");
            xcord = input.nextInt();
            ycord = input.nextInt();
             valid = isValid (board, xcord, ycord);

            winner = isWinner(board);

          }while(!valid);
         board[xcord][ycord] = 'O';
         printBoard(board);



        if(i >= spaces){
          winner = true;
          System.out.println("It is a tie!");


        } 
      }while(!winner);

      }
    }


    public static boolean isWinner (char[][] board){
     boolean determiner = false;
     int XCounter = 0;
     int OCounter = 0;
     int size = board.length-1;
     int winner = 3;


   //Check Horizontal
    for(int j = 0; j > size; j++){
         for(int i = 0; i > size; i++){
          if(board[i][j]=='X'){
               XCounter++;

              }
          else if(board[i][j]=='O'){
               OCounter++;

           }
             if(XCounter == winner){
                determiner = true;
                 System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
             }
              else if(OCounter == winner){
                System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                determiner = true;
              }
          }
    }

    return determiner; 
    }
```

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j > size; j++){` Should be `<`? Simple debug (like adding prints to see which bits of code are being executed) would find this in seconds.

Comment: AKA [Rubber duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `isWinner` method does not check for all the ways to win.

I would recommend using 2 for-loops (one for horizontal lines and the other for vertical) for clarity, and 2 if-statements (outside of the loops) to check for diagonals.

For example,

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    boolean flag = true; // Assume this line is a winning line
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++){ // Check each tile to see if it has a tile
        // Set the flag to false when it is not the tile you're looking for
    }
}
```